# Flutter/Dart - Regex for removing hashtag and spaces?

Tags: regex, flutter, dart, textfield, replaceall

The user is asked to fill in a field with a tag containing no hashtags and no spaces. But some will no doubt do it anyway. How do I strip the hashtags and spaces before sending it off to the database? Here's the code I used to try and simply remove the hashtag. But although it prints the correct removal in the console in realtime as I type into the field, I get the following error when I try to post it off to the server:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s) (input): Must not be null
```

So here's the code;

```
     child: TextField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    autocorrect: false,
                    onChanged: (tag1text){
                      nohash1 = tag1text.replaceAll('#', '');
                      print("This is nohash1 " + nohash1);
                      setState(() {
                        this.tag1 = nohash1;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
```

Comment: Can you give an example of strings as input and write what the expected output should be? I am not sure I understand what you mean by removing spaces. Do you mean all spaces in the text or just at the beginning and end of the strings?

Comment: Where you are using that tag1 ? The issue is probably throwing from that piece of code.

Comment: julemand101 RE: Strings as input  "#big dog sled". expected output "bigdogsled".

Comment: you have not posted the code thats throwing the error

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the good tips. You were all correct that it wasn't the regex throwing the error, it's something else which I'll have to hunt down. But I've accepted the answer from dev-aentgs because it addressed the regex issue in the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `.replaceAll(RegExp('[# ]'),'')` . Your original code only removed matching `#`. Using `RegExp('[# ]')` we can specify the `regex` pattern to use for removal.

```
void main() {
  String inputText = '#big dog sled';
  print(inputText.replaceAll(RegExp('[# ]'),''));
}
```

Output :

```
bigdogsled
```

Comment: I've accepted this because the regex works. Unfortunately my code is still not sending but it looks like that's another issue I've got to troubleshoot.